# FB Share pop up not showing image in Share window

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share a webpage with image to Facebook. I am using following code

In head i have

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://objdevelopment.com/notice/ddfdf" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"  content=" Notice of Passing" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="Notice of Passing " />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://objdevelopment.com/notice/wp-content/uploads/65a4465e9258729f8085c4d780700dad.jpg" />
```

In my body section i have

```
  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.3&appId=937XXXXXXXXXXXX&status=true&cookie=true&xfbml=true";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your share button code -->
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://objdevelopment.com/notice/ddfdf" 
    data-layout="button_count">
</div>
```

But Share popup is not showing any image see screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgM67.png

You can test this at http://objdevelopment.com/notice/onope/ddfdf/

**Update**

After getting help from Stackoverflow, now image is shown in share pop but it is not showing in FB wall. 
Here is you can see how it is displayed in FB wall http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/506649/5ef20c1cd06cbf0878ede934a3a8ef78

Comment: Because the url you are giving the sharer popup is `http://objdevelopment.com/notice/ddfdf`, while your page is `http://objdevelopment.com/notice/onope/ddfdf/`, notice that you are omitting the `onope` part in the url for the sharer popup

Comment: Don't post code in comments, edit your question to include it if you believe it is relevant.

Comment: thanks @PatrickEvans for reminder. i have changed page URL but still image is not showing. however i will look for some other solution.